# textfield only fills till the half CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm actually struggling to find my mistake. I can't force the option by using !important. On another page it works fine. I think I'm overwriting something. I think it has to do with the width of the label, but I'm not sure. I'm relatively new to programming and can't find my mistake. I hope one of you can help me. I've also heard that you should avoid! important anyway.

edit: Unfortunately, the text field only fills up halfway when characters are typed in. I still attach a screenshot.[snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmovj.png)

```css
* {                           /* *-Selector selectiert alles*/
  margin: 0px;                /* Außenabstand */
    padding: 0px;               /* Innenabstand */
    box-sizing: border-box;     /* border, padding, content zählt als width */
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: "Courier", monospace;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.login {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 100px 50px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);     /* Verschiebt es, damit der Kasten mittig ist */
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px #aaaaaa;
}

.login h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    color: #454242;
}

.input {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #454242;
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px 0;
}
.input input {
    width: 100%!important;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-family: "Courier", monospace;
}

.button {
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    font-family: "Courier", monospace;
    color: #454242;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.signUp {
    color: #454242;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.signUp a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #454242;
}

.signUp a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #454242;
}

.signUp a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6a7dfe;
}

.signUp a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #6a7dfe;
}
```

```html
<?php
?>

<!-- _____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ -->

<!-- login ermöglicht den Zugriff auf die Webseite für RN mit richtiger E-Mail und Passwort. Ein Interessent kann von hier
aus zur Registrierung kommen durch "Sign up" -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!--Smartphoneoptimiert-->
    <link href="../css/styleLogin.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- use sessions -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function preventBack() {
          window.history.forward();
        }
        setTimeout("preventBack()",0);
        window.onunload = function() {null};
    </script>



</head>

<body>
    <form class="login" action="sqlProveUser.php" method="POST">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <div class="input">
            <label><b></b></label>
            <input type="email"  name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" />
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label><b></b></label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login">
        <div class="signUp">
            Don't have an account? <a href="signUp.php">Sign up</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'textfield only fills till the half CSS'

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What is the problem? Please update the post. The example looks good so far.

Comment: is the problem (only 20 chars) on both inputs (email and password).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to become a good front-end developer never use "!important" in your code,you must be confident about what you want to make changes to your HTML.
To make a div span multiple rows use must use "vh[view-height]".
for Example

```
.class_name{
height:100vh;
}
```

your whole page is divided into 100 pieces and vh will take that 100 pieces.